# JavaScript Try catch how to call same function in catch to retry

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

In JavaScript Try catch block how to retry the same . am facing once scenario any one ca give the best approach to handle this ?

for Example :

```
const getMyDetails = async()=>{
try{
 await getName();
}catch(err){
 //But Above FAIL due to some issue
 // so I want to try the same again "getName" here until the success - 'not single time'
}

// Second Method for get data 
const getName = async()=>{
try{
 here am calling API or any kind of subscription But here its failing so am throwing error 
}catch(err){
 throw new Error(err);
}

getMyDetails()
```

Note: may be the fail reason like Databse events or some other subscriptions etc..

instead of calling the method name in catch .. what will be the best approach for retry

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just Calling Itself If It Fails Will Do The Job

```
const getMyDetails = async()=>{
try{
 await getName();
}catch(err){
 getMyDetails()
}

// Second Method for get data 
const getName = async()=>{
try{
  // Method
}catch(err){
 throw new Error(err);
}

getMyDetails()
```

Comment: is this best practice ?.. if fails many times .. will call  the same again a and gain ..any other approach ?

Comment: Could you give an example where it fails?

Comment: example like try get my name from DB but the DB is down - have to retry again  just an example

Comment: I Dont See How This Code Fails In That Case.

Comment: When the function calling the database fails (i.e. database is down), the best practice would be to propagate the error along the call-stack because that is an unexpected error without it being the user's fault. Therefore, user should get a 500 http status code response. In this case, repeating the function call would not be efficient because the database could be down for a long time. Slightly better approach would be to try calling the database N number of times, and only then propagate the error if unsuccessful

Comment: Hi @BrunoT  yes . You are correct . so the scenario is like Some DB operations an any  other Event subscription 3rd party server dependency or  something like that . so that is the exact scenarios  .. which approach is the best practice that is the exact questions ..

Comment: Maybe you can set 'retryCount' variable to limit the number of retry.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see an example behavior and the implementation logic of calling an async function N number of times, only until no errors are thrown.

```js
// We must be inside of an async function to be able to call await
(async function() {

  // Example async function which returns the value only if no errors are thrown,
  // otherwise calls itself to retry the async call
  async function getMyDetails() {
    try {
      return await getName();
    } catch (error) {
      return getMyDetails();
    }
  }

  // Example async function which returns value only if the random number is even,
  // otherwise throws an Error (simulating an API error response)
  async function getName() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random());
      if (randomNumber % 2 === 0) {
        resolve("Random Name");
      }
      reject("Example API Error has occured.")
    });
  }

  let myDetails = await getMyDetails();
  console.log(myDetails);
  
})();
```